# Segment a dataframe based on a column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing two columns. One is for a number, the other one is for a Label
Example

```
1 200 A
2 300 B
3 350 C
4 2000 A
5 2200 D
6 2300 K
```

I want basically to segment this dataframe and to transform the second column into a vector containing words in the condition that the difference betweem **any** two values on the first column is < 1000

```
Expected Result is

C("ABC","ADK")
```

Example here we will have a vector C having ABC and ADK as words because the difference between row4 and row3 > 1000

Any idea on how to do it without consuming a lot of computing ?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want. Please post expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edited based on your clarification

```
# SAMPLE DATA
df <- data.frame(Col1=c(200, 300, 350, 2000, 2200, 2300, 4500), Col2=c("A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "K", "M"))
df

# Make sure they are the correct mode
df$Col1 <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Col1))
df$Col2 <- as.character(df$Col2)

lessThan <- which(abs(df$Col1[-length(df$Col1)] - df$Col1[-1]) > 1000 )

lapply(lessThan, function(ind)
  c( paste(df$Col2[1:ind], collapse=""),
      paste(df$Col2[ind+1:length(df$Col2)], collapse="") )
)
```

RESULTS:

```
  [[1]]
  [1] "ABC"   "ADKM"

  [[2]]
  [1] "ABCADK" "M"
```

Comment: Thanks @Ricardo but it is only splitting on a fix value of 1000, the aim here is to get the words split based on the difference between rows in the second column and not on a fixed value 1000

Comment: This can't be right. I don't even understand the meaning of the output. Why a list of two vectors? Do you care to explain, you or @Dar?

Comment: Also it seems you are doing the same mistake I pointed out to @AnandaMahto: you are only looking at distances among consecutive points, when all pairwise distances should be considered.

Comment: @flodel, you may be right.  The above method certainly looks only at consecutive points.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested this on a larger dataset, but the following should work:

```
df <- data.frame(Col1=c(200, 300, 350, 2000, 2200, 2300), 
                 Col2=c("A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "K"))

sapply(split(df$Col2, 
             cumsum(c(1, (diff(df$Col1) > 1000)))), 
       paste, collapse="")
#     1     2 
# "ABC" "ADK"
```

In the above:

- `diff(df$Col1) > 1000` returns a vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE`
- `c(1, (diff(df$Col1) > 1000))` coerces that logical vector into numeric and adds a 1 as the starting point for the first group. Thus, we now have a vector that looks like `1 0 0 1 0 0`.
- We can now use `cumsum()` on that vector to create our "groups" where we want to split the data.
- `sapply` and so on are done to paste the relevant details from `Col2` to get your (named) vector.

Comment: The request is that within a group, the distance between **any** two points be less than 1000. Replace for example 2300 with 3100 and your code would still put 2000, 2200 and 3100 together although the distance between 2000 and 3100 is greater than 1000. Clustering to the rescue!

Answer (score 2):

Yet another answer, only because no-one has mentioned yet that your problem is a classic case of [Cluster Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis). And also because all other answers are wrong in the sense that they are only comparing distances between consecutive points when they should be comparing all pairwise distances.

Finding groups of points within which the distance between any two points is less than a threshold can be handled via [hierarchical clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering), and using [complete linkage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_linkage_clustering). It is very easy with R:

```
df <- data.frame(Col1 = c(200, 300, 350, 2000, 2200, 2300), 
                 Col2 = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "K"))

tree <- hclust(dist(df$Col1), method = "complete")
groups <- cutree(tree, h = 1000)
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2
sapply(split(df$Col2, groups), paste, collapse = "")
#     1     2 
# "ABC" "ADK"
```

Comment: Learn something new every day! +1

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

```
extractGroups <- function(data, threshold){
    #calculate which differences are greater than threshold between values in the first column
    dif <- diff(data[,1]) > threshold

    #edit: as @Ananda suggests, `cumsum` accomplishes these three lines more concisely.

    #identify where the gaps of > threshold are
    dif <- c(which(dif), nrow(data))        
    #identify the length of each of these runs
    dif <- c(dif[1], diff(dif))     
    #create groupings based on the lengths of the above runs
    groups <- inverse.rle(list(lengths=dif, values=1:length(dif)))

    #aggregate by group and paste the characters in the second column together
    aggregate(data[,2], by=list(groups), FUN=paste, collapse="")[,2]
}
```

And an example on your data

```
extractGroups(read.table(text="1 200 A
2 300 B
3 350 C
4 2000 A
5 2200 D
6 2300 K", row.names=1), 1000)

[1] "ABC" "ADK"
```